# How to use ActionBar (via ActionBarSherlock) with GoogleMaps

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing a GoogleMaps v2 API app for android and have encountered a problem. I would like to use an ActionBar (via actionbarsherlock, for backwards-compatability) like in the following figure.

[image: Maps Example]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://www.google.com/mobile/maps/images/c5.png))</sub>

Without adapting my code to have the ActionBar, my maps app works wonderfully. My attempt to conform the code to use it though results in a blank screen and an actionbar. Therefore, the map itself or anything else is loaded.

Code before: (relevant parts only)

```java
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initiate loader, so that files can be acquired in background thread.
        new Loader().execute();   
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have not included imports or variables. Don't worry about that since the code does compile.

Code after:

```java
public class MapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


    public boolean onCreate(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0,SEARCH,0,"Search")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        // Initiate loader, so that files can be acquired in background thread.
        new Loader().execute();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case SEARCH:
                openSearchView();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

EDIT --

Map setup code: (Note that `map` has been declared as a class variable)

```java
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // Recovers map choice from previous activity.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    map_descriptor = intent.getStringExtra(MAP);
    MAP_CENTER = map2LatLng(map_descriptor);

    map = setupMap(map);

    // Initiate loader, so that files can be acquired in background thread.
    new Loader().execute();   
}

public GoogleMap setupMap(GoogleMap map) {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Just in case null map was accidently passed to setupMap.
    }
    map.setMapType(3); // TERRAIN
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(MAP_CENTER)                 
    .zoom(ZOOM_LEVEL)
    .build();

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                ZOOM_LEVEL = cameraPosition.zoom;
                recenterMap(ZOOM_LEVEL);
        }
    });

    return map;
}
```

And XML layout code:

```xml
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: "I would like to use an ActionBar (via actionbarsherlock, for backwards-compatability) while being in fullscreen" -- having an action bar and being in fullscreen mode are mutually exclusive concepts. "like in the following figure" -- neither of those figures show fullscreen mode, by any standard Android definition of "fullscreen".

Comment: Makes sense. What I meant was without TitleBar. Post edited, thanks.

Comment: "What I meant was without TitleBar" -- the action bar *is* the title bar. You cannot simultaneously have an action bar and not have an action bar.

Comment: Well this is the least of my problems really. Post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly setting the content view for the SherlockFragmentActivity, nor are you setting up the map when it expects to be setup.

In your onCreate method, make sure you do something like this after you call super.onCreate().

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
map = setupMap();
```

Even if you're downloading information from somewhere (or whatever you are doing in that asynctask) you still need to set the content view to properly inflate the map in onCreate.

You'll also want to make sure that you call setupMap from onCreate.  You can add markers at a later time.

I've been using SherlockFragmentActivity with Google Maps Android API v2 since the day that API v2 was released, and I've had no issues so it must be the order in which you are creating your view.

Comment: Hey spotdog13, all my onCreate lines are inside the Loader class since I want to make sure I can download all the data before opening the maps fragment. Again, this is working when not using sherlock.

Check: https://github.com/JVUnderground/MapaSara/blob/master/src/com/aquamet/saramap/MapActivity.java (lines 387-414) if possible.

Comment: Humor me and try putting the setContentView and setupMap in the onCreate.  I'm guessing that ABS tries to attach to whatever view is loaded in onCreate and because the map has not yet been loaded it takes over the entire screen and no map is shown.

On another note, I really don't think it is the correct flow to make sure you can download all the map data before showing the map.  I think it would be better to show the map right away, then download data in the background with a ProgressDialog that says "Loading..." or something similar until it's done, and exit the map if the download fails.

Comment: Like I said, I've been using ABS + Maps v2 since the day it was released with 0 issues and the only difference between our implementations is that you're not calling setContentView or setupMap in onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Maps V1 with ActionBarSherlock, you need [the add-on JAR for maps support](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/downloads) -- basically a `MapActivity` that knows about ActionBarSherlock.

If you are going to use Maps V2 with ActionBarSherlock, you would typically load the map via a fragment, such as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Basic). Nowhere does your sample code show how you are getting the map in there, and as such it is difficult to guess why the map is not displaying for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have v2 key, therefore cannot use MapActivity.

Comment: @jhc: Updated for Maps V2. You might want to post the code where you are adding the map to your UI -- if your problem is that this code is not working, we would need to see that code.

Comment: I edited the post. Not sure if it's absolutely needed since the map was being loaded normally before actionbar implementation.

Comment: @jhc: Take a look at the sample app I linked to from my answer and determine where you are doing things differently, then.

Comment: I have given a look at the code sample, you use a custom  AbstractMapActivity class, but I'm pretty sure that I'm doing the same  by extending SherlockFragmentActivity. Check out edited post and link:

https://github.com/JVUnderground/MapaSara